# How to list only certain files in R?

Tags: r

I have thousands of different files (having the same extension `.img`) in a folder called `data`. If I use this :

```
 dir<- list.files ("C:\\Users\\data", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
```

It will list all files I have in the folder `data`.

What I need is just to list the files named as:

```
 File_yyyymmdd_data.img     (in which yyyymmdd varies for 10 years)
```

Any idea or hint is appreciated!

Comment: Use the `pattern` parameter with an appropriate regular expression, i.e., change the regex in the second parameter.

Comment: Then study `help("list.files")`.

Comment: Could you show a couple of actual cases on how the file names might be. And some that you do not want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

`files.new = list.files(directory.path, recursive = TRUE, pattern=".img")`

Where, "directory.path" is the path to the directory containing files you need to read

---

edited

to be more appropriate

```
files.new = list.files(directory.path, recursive = TRUE, pattern="File_[0-9]{8}_data[.]img$")
```

Comment: Your pattern isn’t a valid regular expression, and it will match something different from what you think.

Comment: No, it’s still wrong. R swallows it but yields wrong results. For instance, your pattern will match the file name `trimgoose`, which is probably not expected.

Comment: The `pattern` argument should be something like `"File_[0-9]{8}_data[.]img$"`.

Comment: do `paste("path.of.the.directory", files.new, sep =  "/")`

Comment: or else keep the directory with files inside another directory (lets say "parent directory") and set the `directory.path` with the path to the parent directory

Comment: How do I get the "folders"? Whats should be the pattern for that?