# Reading a lot of text files into R

Tags: r, text, tm

I have a lot of text files which represent messages. I want to analyze them in the [tm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) in R, so I need to get them into R. What is an efficient way to read all the words in the messages into R? Something like:

```
txts <- Sys.glob("*.txt")
for (f in txts) {
tempData <- as.data.frame(scan(f, what="raw", quiet = TRUE))
 data <- rbind(data, tempData)
 }
```

simply takes forever and doesn't work very well. How do I read all the complete words in all the files and get them into R quickly?

Bonus trickery: Some of the files seem to have been generated weirdly and now have some words on a new line like

```
  h
  e
  l
  l
  o
```

Is there a way to either ignore words that are really short (already when reading them into R) or to make R string them all together?

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: My apologies! Removed the tag.

Comment: Trying looking into `fread` & `rbindlist` in the `data.table` package (in place of `scan` and `rbind`).

Comment: @JaapBaanders May be you could read the files and store them in a list object and then use lapply to do what you are doing in for loop. this will solve your execution time issue. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800711/how-to-list-only-certain-files-in-r/29800819#29800819) you can find how to  read multiple files and store in a list object.

Comment: Just emphasizing what @nrussell said.